# Google Hangouts API for video calling web app

Tags: javascript, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I want to develop a video calling web application for desktop browsers. I tried Google Hangouts API, but it can only start a new Hangout, so the receiver can answer only with the Hangout App (external app). Is it possible to use Google Hangouts API in order to integrate all video call's functionality in my app? For example, answer to the Hangout call in my app.